# adding checkmarks to recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to make the **RecyclerView** have **checkmarks** like in **ListView**? Most of the example i see don't have checkmark-like features. They instead highlight the row when the user clicks on an item in the list which is not the behavior i desire. Please any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Check marks meaning check boxes??

Comment: sorry for the late reply @Raghunandan . Yes meaning check boxes

Comment: Its the same way as listview except you use recyclerview.

Comment: @user3137376 did my reply help?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this :

First, Have a [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html)  in your adapter that you initialize in the constructor. SparseBooleanArrays map integers to booleans so you can know which view has been selected and which hasn't.

```
 public class RecyclerAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.DataViewHolder> {
    private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;
    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataList){
        selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }
```

The ViewHolder implements a ClickListener:

```
  public  class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // the condition below returns false if the item isn't in the array.
            if (selectedItems.get(getPosition(), false)) {
              //if it is in the array we delete it. So clicking a second time on an item will uncheck it.
                selectedItems.delete(getPosition());
                ((CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(selectedItems.get(position, false));
            }
            else {
                selectedItems.put(getPosition(), true);
                // here get a ref to the view checkbox and *check* it
                ((CheckBox)viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

At this point you will have multiples items with a checked checkbox in your recyclerview since views are recycled. To prevent this and have only the checkboxes you want to be checked change your onBindViewHolder method so it checks or unchecks the checkbox at bind time :

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        ((CheckBox)viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(selectedItems.get(position, false));
    }
```

I didn't test it but I've almost the same code and it works. If you have a problem let me know.